# Can't open MuPDF via shell in macOS

Tags: latex, homebrew, macos-sierra

I can't seem to open MuPDF by issuing a command. I installed it via Homebrew and when I type:

```
mupdf
```

...nothing happens. I found a thread on here where a solution was to type in:

```
mupdf-x11
```

But that didn't help me either.

I looked in the directory for the binaries and mutools is there along with some other stuff, but I'm just looking for the binary for the viewer.

Comment: What’s the exit code? Type `mupdf` then when you get a prompt back type `echo $?`. If it’s `0`, `mupdf` exited correctly; otherwise it encountered an error.

Comment: `echo $status` (I'm using fish) gave me a `127`

Comment: I’m not on my machine right now but maybe `mupdf` has a verbose or debug flag to print more info about its failure?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with mupdf-x11 (exit code 127), and was able to fix it by adding

```
alias mupdf='mupdf-gl'
```

to my .zshrc